# React Router Link in <select> <option>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

there I'm trying to filter some date using React Router Link in `select` box with 4 `options` in it. When I wrap the `options` with a Router Link I don't see values in the `select` box (is empty), any idea's?

Here is what I have so far.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 80% 10%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0;
`;

const LinkQuery = styled(Link)`
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary};
`;

export const SelectBox = styled.select`
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
  border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.primary};
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary};
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    transition: 0.4s;
    border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.tertiary};
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
`;

export default function LocationFilter() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <SelectBox>
        <LinkQuery to="/">
          <option>Select Location</option>
        </LinkQuery>
        <LinkQuery to="/?location=east">
          <option>East Building</option>
        </LinkQuery>
        <LinkQuery to="/?location=west">
          <option>West Building</option>
        </LinkQuery>
        <LinkQuery to="/?location=south">
          <option>South Building</option>
        </LinkQuery>
        <LinkQuery to="/?location=north">
          <option>North Building</option>
        </LinkQuery>
      </SelectBox>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why can you just use a normal select and option HTML. Then on the `onChange` event get the selected value then push the new history to your router. The issue is here is using a library with the wrong api.

Comment: What version and package is your router?

Comment: I'm using "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2". I'm fetching my data from JSON DB, no external API or package.

Comment: "react-router": "^5.1.2",

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution to my problem. I use `useHistory` hook from `React Router`.
The functional code for my problem looks like this.

```
export default function LocationFilter() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleChange(value) {
    history.push(`/?location=${value}`);
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <SelectBox onChange={event => handleChange(event.target.value)}>
        <option>Select Location</option>
        <option value="east">East Building</option>
        <option value="west">West Building</option>
        <option value="south">South Building</option>
        <option value="north">North Building</option>
      </SelectBox>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const LocationFilter = () =>{
 let navigate = useNavigate();
 LocationFilter()
  function handleChange(value) {
    navigate(`${value}`);
    value = "";
  }
return (
    <Wrapper>
      <SelectBox onChange={event => handleChange(event.target.value)}>
        <option>Select Location</option>
        <option value="east">East Building</option>
        <option value="west">West Building</option>
        <option value="south">South Building</option>
        <option value="north">North Building</option>
      </SelectBox>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
export {LocationFilter}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).